# Is there a way to find the number of prime factors of a given integer?

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring

I am trying implement a function to factoring a number, and so far I have this code:

```
int * factor(int n) {
  int * vet;
  //
  int p = 2;
  int index = 0;
  while(n > 1) {
    while(n % p != 0) {
      p++;
      index++;
    }
    n = n / p;
    vet[index]++;
  }
  return vet;
}
```

this function should return a array with the powers of each prime factor of the number `n`. like that:

if 1200 = 2x2x2x2x3x5x5, then 1200 = 2^4 + 3^1 + 5^1, and so the function should return the array {4,1,0,3} if 1200 was the parameter.

of if 440 = 2x2x2x5x11, then 440 = x^3 + 5^1 + 11^1, and the function should return the array {3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1}

my question is about if exists some way to determine the size of `vet` before I start the factoration process, in the `while` loop.

also, with this resulting array (or with some variation of the concept above), is it possible find the powers of 2 for this number? for example:

440 = 1x2^8 + 1x2^7 + 0x2^6 + 1x2^5 + 1x2^4 + 1x2^3 + 0x2^2 + 0x2^1 + 0x2^0
resulting in the array {1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0}

1200 = 1x2^10 + 0x2^9 + 0x2^8 + 1x2^7 + 0x2^6 + 1x2^5 + 1x2^4 + 0x2^3 + 0x2^2 + 0x2^1 + 0x2^0
resulting in the array {1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}

Comment: As an initial matter, `vet` is an uninitialized variable, and your code exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing it.

Comment: If you have a specific problem with your code, please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate it. If you have no specific problem, then what kind of answer do you expect? StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. If this is a homework assignment you might find this interesting https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My question is exactly about that: how I could find a value `n` to replace the comented line by something like `vet = malloc(n)` or `vet = new int(n)`.

Comment: `std::vector<int> vet;`. Now you have one fewer problems.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but the problem remains if I am not able to use `std:vetor` here; is it really not possible allocate an array for this, finding a value for the length?

Comment: What's stopping you from using `std::vector` here? Finding the number of prime factors will require the same amount of work as finding the factors themselves. You could, if you are so inclined, run the algorithm twice - first time just counting, and second time actually storing the values.

Comment: One way to do it is to write a program to mimic the way you'd do it manually. For example, https://www.mathsisfun.com/prime-factorization.html.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution which is of the quickest time:

```
void getFactors(int n)
{
    while (n%2 == 0)
    {
        n = n/2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i = i+2)
    {
        // While i divides n, print i and divide n
        while (n%i == 0)
        {  
            std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

}
```